# TryCatch in a loop - R

Tags: r, try-catch

my initial loop is the following:

```
 for(iRow in seq(1,nrow(df),1)){


valueTMP <- df$Set_C[iRow]
strikeTMP <- df$`Exercise price`[iRow]
underlyingTMP <- df$Compens.[iRow]
dividendyieldTMP <- df$RFR[iRow]
riskfreerateTMP <- df$RFR[iRow]
maturityTMP <- df$maturity[iRow]


  df$IV[iRow] <- AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility("call", valueTMP, underlyingTMP, strikeTMP,dividendyieldTMP, riskfreerateTMP, maturityTMP, 0.4)

  }
```

This loop returns a value up to a certain row. I want to use `TryCatch` with it so I tried the following. However, it does not change anything to the previous result. I think something is missing in the code, that would make it return something even after error messages.

```
for(iRow in seq(1,nrow(df),1)){


 valueTMP <- df$Set_C[iRow]
 strikeTMP <- df$`Exercise price`[iRow]
 underlyingTMP <- df$Compens.[iRow]
 dividendyieldTMP <- df$RFR[iRow]
 riskfreerateTMP <- df$RFR[iRow]
 maturityTMP <- df$maturity[iRow]


#ERROR HANDLING
possibleError <- tryCatch(
  thing(),
  error=function(e) e
)

    if(inherits(possibleError, "error")) next
  df$IV[iRow] <- AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility("call", valueTMP, 
underlyingTMP, strikeTMP, dividendyieldTMP, riskfreerateTMP, maturityTMP, 0.4)

  }
```

Does anyone know how to make it work until the last observation, even though for some rows it won't run?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This worked although it takes a lot of time to run:

```
 for(iRow in seq(1,nrow(df),1)){


valueTMP <- df$Set_P[iRow]
strikeTMP <- df$`Exercise price`[iRow]
underlyingTMP <- df$Compens.[iRow]
dividendyieldTMP <- df$RFR[iRow]
riskfreerateTMP <- df$RFR[iRow]
maturityTMP <- df$maturity[iRow]


try(  df$IV[iRow] <- AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility("put", valueTMP, underlyingTMP, 
strikeTMP,dividendyieldTMP, riskfreerateTMP,  maturityTMP, 0.4))
if (inherits(df$IV, "try-error")) next

  }
```